# I constantly need to reload window on VS Code for intellisense to suggest React and other installed packages. How can I prevent needing to reload?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

[The suggestion for React's create context is usually not there/suggested after a long enough session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C7V7.png)

[After using the reload command, the suggestions always appears as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VldSU.png)

Intellisense stops suggesting installed packages after a long session. My current guaranteed fix is just reloading window when I notice the issue. However, is there an underlying issue that can prevent this altogether?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Intellisense basically completely stops working even after a not too long session. I'll suddenly get the "Configure Excludes" message, but when I reload the window, Intellisense works again, and I'm not prompted to configure excludes. You could update you jsconfig.json to exclude more files, but I'm already excluding as much as I can.